# Translating boost::thread->native_handle() to XP ThreadId

Tags: winapi, boost-thread

I've managed to get the Windows ThreadId out of the **native_handle()** from a **boost::thread** by using **GetThreadId(HANDLE)**. Sadly that call is not available on Windows XP and after searching around I found the solution to offer als fallback support for XP by traversing all thread via **Thread32First()** and **Thread32Next()** functions of the WINAPI.

This does work somehow but my problem is I'm currently only able to identify the threads of my process... I don't now how to match the **native_handle()** / **HANDLE** from one side with the appropriate **THREADENTRY32** from the loop traversal.

```
THREADENTRY32 te32;
//...
do { 
    if( te32.th32OwnerProcessID == GetCurrentProcessId() ) {
        DWORD threadId = te32.th32ThreadID;
        printf( "\n     THREAD ID      = 0x%08X", te32.th32ThreadID ); 
    }
} while( Thread32Next(hThreadSnap, &te32 ) );
```

Can anyone help me with that? How do I convert a boost::thread->native_handle() to the ThreadId on WindowsXP?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass each thread ID in the loop to [`OpenThread()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684335.aspx) until you find a matching `HANDLE`.  For example:

```
HANDLE hBoostThread = ...; // from boost::thread->native_handle()
DWORD dwBoostThreadID = 0;

THREADENTRY32 te32;
//...
do
{ 
    if( te32.th32OwnerProcessID == GetCurrentProcessId() )
    {
        HANDLE hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, te32.th32ThreadID);
        if (hThread != NULL)
        {
            if (hThread == hBoostThread)
            {
                CloseHandle(hThread);
                dwBoostThreadID = te32.th32ThreadID; 
                break;
            }
            CloseHandle(hThread);
        }
    }
}
while( Thread32Next(hThreadSnap, &te32 ) );
```

For good measure, you can wrap this inside a function that you can call whenever `GetThreadId()` is not natively available so that your code does not need to know the difference, eg:

```
DWORD WINAPI MyGetThreadId(HANDLE Thread)
{
    THREADENTRY32 te32;

    HANDLE hThreadSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);
    if (hThreadSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return 0;

    if (Thread32First(hThreadSnap, &te32))
    {
        do
        { 
            HANDLE hOpenThread = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, te32.th32ThreadID);
            if (hOpenThread != NULL)
            {
                if (hOpenThread == Thread)
                {
                    CloseHandle(hOpenThread);
                    CloseHandle(hThreadSnap);
                    return te32.th32ThreadID; 
                }

                CloseHandle(hOpenThread);
            }
        }
        while( Thread32Next(hThreadSnap, &te32 ) );
    }

    CloseHandle(hThreadSnap);
    return 0;
}
```

```
typedef DWORD (WINAPI *LPFN_GTID)(HANDLE);

LPFN_GTID lpGetThreadId = (LPFN_GTID) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32"), "GetThreadId");
if (!lpGetThreadId)
    lpGetThreadId = &MyGetThreadId;
```

```
DWORD dwThreadID = lpGetThreadId((HANDLE) boost::thread->native_handle());
```

With that said, a better option is to directly query the target thread itself for its own ID, instead of trying to hunt for it manually:

```
typedef long (WINAPI *LPFN_NTQIT)(HANDLE thread, int infoclass, void *buf, long size, long *used);

typedef struct _THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION
{
    ULONG ExitStatus;
    void* TebBaseAddress;
    ULONG UniqueProcessId;
    ULONG UniqueThreadId;
    ULONG AffinityMask;
    ULONG BasePriority;
    ULONG DiffProcessPriority;
} THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION;

DWORD WINAPI MyGetThreadId(HANDLE Thread)
{
    DWORD dwThreadId = 0;

    HMODULE hLib = LoadLibrary("ntdll.dll");
    if (hLib != NULL)
    {
        LPFN_NTQIT lpNtQueryInformationThread = (LPFN_NTQIT) GetProcAddress(hLib, "NtQueryInformationThread");

        if (lpNtQueryInformationThread != NULL)
        {
            THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION tbi = {0};
            ULONG used = 0;

            if (lpNtQueryInformationThread(Thread, 0, &tbi, sizeof(tbi), &used) == 0)
                dwThreadId = tbi.UniqueThreadId;
        }

        FreeLibrary(hLib);
    }

    return dwThreadId;
}
```